# How do you upgrade a Snapshot space on Endurance storage using SoftLayer API?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Using SoftLayer API, I've ordered an Endurance Block Storage and it's there.
Now I am trying to write a PHP code that will use SoftLayer API to modify Snapshot space, but I keep getting this error:

```
There was an error querying the SoftLayer API: Price does not have an id.
```

And I am not sure what the issue is.
Below is bit of code that I am using to do this:

```
$clientServer = SoftLayer_XmlrpcClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Product_Order', null, userID, apiKey);
$clientServer->verifyOrder($order);
```

And the $order that I pass is below and the price ID I pass is correct as far as I know.  So what am I missing?  Or do I need to do this in different way?

```
{
   "categoryCode" : "storage_snapshot_space",
   "complexType" : "Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise_SnapshotSpace_Upgrade",
   "packageId" : 240,
   "prices" : [
      {
         "id" : 144295
      }
   ],
   "properties" : [
      {
         "name" : "orderOrigin",
         "value" : "control"
      }
   ],
   "virtualGuests" : null
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Json should be something like this, where the volumeId is the block storage id where the upgrade will be applied.

```
{
  "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise_SnapshotSpace_Upgrade",
  "packageId": 240,
  "prices": [{

    "id": 144295
  }],

  "volumeId": 5805095
}
```

In PHP it would be like this:

```
<?php

require_once ('C:/scripst/getdetails/SoftLayer/SoapClient.class.php');

$username = 'set me';
$key = 'set me';


$softLayer_product_order = SoftLayer_SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Product_Order', null, $username, $key);


$prices = array
(
    46150
);


$orderPrices = array();

foreach ($prices as $priceId){
    $price = new stdClass();
    $price->id = $priceId;
    $orderPrices[] = $price;
}

$packageId = 240;

$volumeId = 5805095;

$orderContainer = new stdClass();
$orderContainer->packageId          = $packageId;
$orderContainer->prices             = $orderPrices;
$orderContainer->volumeId           = $volumeId;

try {

    $orderTemplate = new SoapVar
    (
        $orderContainer,
        SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
        'SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise_SnapshotSpace_Upgrade',
        'http://api.service.softlayer.com/soap/v3/'
    );

    $receipt = $softLayer_product_order->verifyOrder($orderTemplate);
    print_r($receipt);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Unable to place the order: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Do not forget replace the prices and the volumeID

Regards

Comment: Thank you! This works!
Looks like the main thing I missed is I missed the "SoftLayer_" prefix in complexType. I can't believe I missed that... Thank you again!