# Unable to order snapshot space

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I see that my volume does not have space. Both, the SL portal and SL API confirm that there is no snapshot space. 
The volume object in question has these details (There is no 'snapshotCapacityGb')-

{'username': 'XXX', 'capacityGb': 100, 'hostId': '', 'serviceProviderId': 1, 'nasType': 'NAS', 'upgradableFlag': True, 'storageTypeId': '13', 'createDate': '2016-09-26T18:06:09+05:30', 'serviceResourceName': 'XXX', 'hardwareId': '', 'serviceResourceBackendIpAddress': 'XXX.service.softlayer.com', 'notes': '', 'guestId': '', 'id': XXX, 'accountId': XXX}

Yet, while trying to order snapshot space via SL API, I get an error that the **volume already has snapshot space**.

What could be the reason for such error?

```
check_order = SL.instance(sl_config).storage_order.verifyOrder(order)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 385, in call_handler
  return self(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 353, in call
  return self.client.call(self.name, name, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 256, in call
  return self.transport(request)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/transports.py", line 187, in __call__
  raise _ex(ex.faultCode, ex.faultString)
SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): The storage volume with id XXXX already has snapshot space
```

Answer (score 0):

It would have be great to see your code :S, basically if you already have the snapshot space you need to upgrade it, when you perform the upgrade you need to make sure you are using the proper order container otherwise it will fail.

take a look this example:

[How do you upgrade a Snapshot space on Endurance storage using SoftLayer API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097711/how-do-you-upgrade-a-snapshot-space-on-endurance-storage-using-softlayer-api)

regards

Comment: Out of curiosity I checked the SL portal. The portal showed snapshot space to be 0. I then tried to set snapshot space through portal. And to my surprise the portal also returned the error saying volume already has snapshot space !

So this seems to be some issue with SL volume itself and not really a problem with SL Python API.

Comment: if that is the case, I recomed you to submit a ticket and ask softlayer's guys