# How to create block storage from snapshot using softlayer api

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ibm-cloud-storage

I have created snapshot of block storage. Now I need to create a duplicate block storage from the snapshot.

unable to find the softlayer api to create block storage from snapshot, Please help on this

Comment: please review this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830919/unable-to-order-snapshot-space

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Daniel Cabero. Need to create block storage from already created snapshot. No need to upgrade snapshot space. Can u help me?

Comment: please review this link https://sldn.softlayer.com/python/createSnapshot/

Comment: This question was already answered in the following forum: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65610081/how-to-create-duplicate-block-storage-from-snapshot-using-softlayer-rest-api