# Ordering block volume's snapshot space API is failing

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I was trying to create block volume snapshot space like as follows, but getting following **error**

> error:SoftLayer_Exception_Public: The price for 10 GB Storage Space
>   (#144295) is not valid for location dal09. (HTTP 500)

Can you please suggest what is the issue.

code:

```
dcname := "dal09"
locationObj := sls.backend.GetLocationService()
locations, err := locationObj.GetDatacenters()
datacenterID := 0
for _, location := range locations {
    if *location.Name == dcname {
        sls.logger.Info("Got location ID: ", zap.Object("ID", *location.Id))
        datacenterID = *location.Id
        break
    }
}
pricesT := []datatypes.Product_Item_Price{
    datatypes.Product_Item_Price{ Id: sl.Int(144295) },  // 10 GB
}

cpo := datatypes.Container_Product_Order {
    ComplexType   : sl.String("SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise_SnapshotSpace_Upgrade"),
    Quantity      : sl.Int(1),
    Location      : sl.String(strconv.Itoa(datacenterID)),
    PackageId     : sl.Int(240),
    Prices        : pricesT,
}

sp := datatypes.Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise_SnapshotSpace {
    VolumeId: sl.Int(volid),
    Container_Product_Order : cpo,
}
orderContainer := &datatypes.Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise_SnapshotSpace_Upgrade{
    Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise_SnapshotSpace : sp,
}

productOrderObj := sls.backend.GetProductOrderService()
snorderID, snerr := productOrderObj.PlaceOrder(orderContainer, sl.Bool(false))
sls.logger.Info("Snapshot order details ... ", zap.Object("orderID", snorderID), zap.Error(snerr))
```

Comment: I am able to create snapshot with package ID: 759 and price id: 194949

Answer (score 0):

To order block volume snapshot space you do not have to use “SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise_SnapshotSpace_Upgrade” because it is just to upgrade a snapshot space in a volume.

You just have to use "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise_SnapshotSpace".

Bellow there is a example how to add a snapshot space to a block volume.

```
/*
SnapshotSpace

This is the datatype that needs to be populated and sent to SoftLayer_Product_Order::placeOrder.
This datatype has everything required to place an order for Enterprise Storage Snapshot Space.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise_SnapshotSpace/

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
*/

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/datatypes"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/services"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/session"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/sl"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    // SoftLayer API username and key
    username := "set me"
    apikey   := "set me"

    // Declare the properties like complexType, location, packageId and
    // volumeId
    complexType := "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise_SnapshotSpace"
    location    := "DALLAS09"
    packageId   := 240
    volumeId    := 11111


    prices := []datatypes.Product_Item_Price{
        { Id: sl.Int( 22222) },     // 10 GB
    }

    cpo := datatypes.Container_Product_Order {
        ComplexType   : sl.String(complexType),
        Location      : sl.String(location),
        PackageId     : sl.Int(packageId),
        Prices        : prices,
    }

    sp := datatypes.Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise_SnapshotSpace {
        VolumeId: sl.Int(volumeId),
        Container_Product_Order : cpo,
    }


    // Create a session
    sess := session.New(username, apikey)

    // Get SoftLayer_Product_Order service
    service := services.GetProductOrderService(sess)

    // Use verifyOrder() method to check for errors. Replace this with placeOrder() when
    // you are ready to order.
    receipt, err := service.VerifyOrder(&sp)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("\n Unable to place order:\n - %s\n", err)
        return
    }

    // Following helps to get the result in json format.
    // Following helps to print the result in json format.
    jsonFormat, jsonErr := json.MarshalIndent(receipt, "", "    ")
    if jsonErr != nil {
        fmt.Println(jsonErr)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(string(jsonFormat))
}
```

To get the item prices and their respective locations available you can use the following example:

```
/*
GetItemPrices

Retrieve a collection of SoftLayer_Product_Item_Prices that are valid for this package.

Important manual pages:
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices/

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
*/

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/services"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/session"
    "encoding/json"
    "terraform-provider-softlayer/softlayer"
)


func main() {
    softlayer.Provider()

    // SoftLayer API username and key
    username := "set me"
    apikey   := "set me"

    packageId := 240
    mask := "id;locationGroupId;item[id,keyName,description];pricingLocationGroup[locations[id, name, longName]]"

    // Create a session
    sess := session.New(username, apikey)

    service := services.GetProductPackageService(sess)

    receipt, err := service.Id(packageId).Mask(mask).GetItemPrices()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("\n Unable to retrieve the item prices:\n - %s\n", err)
        return
    }

    // Following helps to get the result in json format.
    // Following helps to print the result in json format.
    jsonFormat, jsonErr := json.MarshalIndent(receipt, "", "    ")
    if jsonErr != nil {
        fmt.Println(jsonErr)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(string(jsonFormat))
}
```

The item prices that do not have locations are standard, it means that all the locations are available for them.

If you want to upgrade the snapshot space see this link: [How do you upgrade a Snapshot space on Endurance storage using SoftLayer API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097711/how-do-you-upgrade-a-snapshot-space-on-endurance-storage-using-softlayer-api)

Comment: thanks Ojeda, I was able to get the price and package ID as well by using api