# How to order snapshot space from Block Storage using Rest API

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to place order but some error came
Rest API: https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder

BODY: { "parameters": [ { "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise_SnapshotSpace", "packageId": 240, "prices": [ { "id": 201527 } ], "volumeId": 200326976 } ] }

Response: {"error":"The price for 20 GB Storage Space (#201527) is not valid for location ams01.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this body

```
 {
   "parameters":[
      {
         "complexType":"SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise",
         "location":"AMSTERDAM",
         "quantity":1,
         "packageId":240,
         "prices":[
            {"id": 45098},      # Block Storage         keyName: storage_block
            {"id": 45058},      # Endurance Storage     keyName: storage_service_enterprise
            {"id": 45138},      # 20 GB Storage Space   keyName: performance_storage_space
            {"id": 45088},      # 4 IOPS per GB         keyName: storage_tier_level
            {"id": 46140}       # 5 GB Storage Space    keyName: storage_snapshot_space
         ],
         "osFormatType":{
            "keyName":"LINUX"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

references

https://sldn.softlayer.com/python/order_endurance_storage/
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Object/
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getAllObjects/
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices/

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response, I have created volume but not created snapshot space, How to order snapshot space using volume id?

Comment: basically, if you already have the snapshot space you need to upgrade it, when you perform the upgrade you need to make sure you are using the proper order container otherwise it will fail.

take a look at this example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097711/how-do-you-upgrade-a-snapshot-space-on-endurance-storage-using-softlayer-api

Answer (score 0):

An error like a specific price is not valid for location, usually means that this item price is not valid for one specific location, so in order to fix your order, you can try to use standard prices, which can be used with any location when ordering.

In a SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price datatype, if "[locationGroupId](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price/#locationgroupid)" is null, the price is considered a standard price.
On the other hand, you are using 201527  price id, wich item "keyName" is "20_GB_PERFORMANCE_STORAGE_SPACE", then knowing these values you can build an object [filter](https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters/) as below:

```
 objectFilter={
      "itemPrices": {
        "locationGroupId": {
          "operation": "is null"
        },
        "item": {
          "keyName": {
            "operation": "20_GB_PERFORMANCE_STORAGE_SPACE"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

and you can retrieval all standard prices by using a rest API call like:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/240/getItemPrices?objectFilter={"itemPrices":{"locationGroupId":{"operation":"is null"},"item":{"keyName": { "operation" : "20_GB_PERFORMANCE_STORAGE_SPACE"}}}}&objectMask=mask[id,item[keyName,description],locationGroupId]
```

response example:

```
[
    {
        "id": 46659,
        "locationGroupId": null,
        "item": {
            "description": "20 GB Storage Space",
            "keyName": "20_GB_PERFORMANCE_STORAGE_SPACE"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 45128,
        "locationGroupId": null,
        "item": {
            "description": "20 GB Storage Space",
            "keyName": "20_GB_PERFORMANCE_STORAGE_SPACE"
        }
    },
```

For instance, try to use a standard price retrieved above in your JSON body, also you can just check it by using the verify method:

POST:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder
```

BODY:

```
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise_SnapshotSpace",
      "packageId": 240,
      "prices": [
        {
          "id": 45128
        }
      ],
      "quantity": 1,
      "location": "AMSTERDAM",
      "volumeId": 200326976
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @german eduardo.
I used above API as per suggestion, But I'm getting the below mentioned error when I executing 

"{"error":"The order package #240 doesn't match the billing records of volume #200465886 which is linked to package #759.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Order"}"

Please help me with this

Comment: you can get prices for package 759 in the same way that above,https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/759/getItemPrices, keep in mind  that retrieved prices has different capacities restrictions as Storage Tier Levels capacity and IOPS capacity, these should match with with your storage, for instance, you can try with a body as: {"parameters": [{"complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise_SnapshotSpace", "packageId": 759, "prices": [{"id": 196513}], "quantity": 1, "location": "AMSTERDAM", "volumeId": 200326976}]}